# Opening torrent with Deluge using Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, deluge

I'm new to Linux. I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu to open a torrent seed file. I want to use the "open with" feature to open it with Deluge and not Transmission (my default client). However, I don't see Deluge listed as an option, and I'm not sure where to find it. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be at `/usr/bin/deluge`.  If you already have a Firefox default saved, you can change it by going to Edit->Preferences->Applications, searching for torrent, then clicking the action item, then Use other..., then entering the deluge filename.